# Video will not show up in Photos on Android 24 using FileProvider and MediaScan

Tags: android, video, mediastore

I am kind of stuck on this one and have been working on it for a little while with no luck. I have an android application which allows the user to take photos/videos. The files are stored on external storage using a FileProvider. I have been trying (without luck) to get the videos to show up in the Photos app and have not been able to. The Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE and sendBroadcast works perfect for images but does not work on video. I know the videos are being captured, they are being saved in the correct location, and are not corrupted (i can play them in VideoView using FileProvider content Uri) I have not attempted to update this to Android 10 yet as my minimum target is 24 and i cannot seem to get it to work for that.

Creating the Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE and sendBroadcast the video does not show up. If i use MediaScannerConnection it does not show up. If i manually insert with the content resolver using the content URI it shows up in Photos but video is not playable and there is no preview. If i manually insert into the content resolver with the absolute path it does not show up at all in Photos
Below is the code i use to take the video and add to the MediaStore

File Provider

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

File Provider Paths

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="Image" path="Image" />
    <external-files-path name="Recording" path="Recording"/>
    <external-files-path name="Video" path="Video"/>
</paths>
```

Methods to create the file and call Intent to capture video

```
private fun takeVideo() {

        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE).also{ videoIntent ->
            val videoFile: File? = try{
                createVideoFile()
            }catch(ex: IOException){
                Toast.makeText(mMainActivityHelper.contextProvider(), R.string.error_taking_photo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.w("OPENING_VIDEO_FILE", "Error opening video file with message = " + ex.message)
                return
            }
            mFilePath = Uri.parse(videoFile?.absolutePath)
            videoFile?.also{
                videoIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                mFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mMainActivityHelper.contextProvider(), "FileProvider", it)
                videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mFileUri)
           mMainActivityHelper.startActivityForResult(videoIntent, MainActivity.TAKE_VIDEO)
       }
   }
}



@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun createVideoFile(): File? {
    val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
    val externalDir = mMainActivityHelper.externalFilesDirProvider(null)
    val imagePath = File(externalDir, "NuNoteVideo")

    if(!imagePath.exists())
        imagePath.mkdir()

    return File(imagePath.path, "MPEG_${timeStamp}" + ".mp4")
}
```

OnActivityResult code i have tried and none of it has worked. I have tried with both the content URI and the absolute path with no luck

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

```
    when{
          requestCode == TAKE_VIDEO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK->{

            val cv = ContentValues(3).apply {
                val absolutePath = myObjectWithThePath.mFilePath.toString()
                val name = absolutePath.substring(absolutePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
                put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, name)
                put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
                put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
                put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, Date().time)
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, absolutePath)
                contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, this)
            }

            Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE).also { mediaScanIntent ->
                val fileUri = myObjectWithThePath.mFileUri

                if(fileUri != null) {
                    val f = File(fileUri)
                    mediaScanIntent.data = Uri.fromFile(f)
                    //mediaScanIntent.type = "video/mp4"
                    sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent)
                }
            }

            val f = File(myObjectWithThePath.mFilePath.toString())

            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(applicationContext, listOf(f.absolutePath).toTypedArray(), listOf("video/mp4").toTypedArray()){
                path, uri ->

                print(path)
                print(uri) //This shows a URI if i use the absolute path but nothing shows up in the photos app. If i use content uri with FileProvider is null
            }
```

I have looked at many many many anwsers on Stack already and nothing has worked. Any help is greatly appreciated

[Video not shown on Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116743/video-not-shown-on-gallery)

[MediaScanner and ScopedStorage on SDK-29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57963282/mediascanner-and-scopedstorage-on-sdk-29)

[MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE not saving the video in Nougat 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771699/mediastore-action-video-capture-not-saving-the-video-in-nougat-7-0)

[ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE from external sdcard Lollipop+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35346937/action-media-scanner-scan-file-from-external-sdcard-lollipop)

[Saving photos and videos using Android FileProvider to the gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247674/saving-photos-and-videos-using-android-fileprovider-to-the-gallery)

[android - save image into gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560501/android-save-image-into-gallery/8722494#8722494)

[MediaScannerConnection doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971263/mediascannerconnection-doesnt-work)

[Android How to use MediaScannerConnection scanFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646913/android-how-to-use-mediascannerconnection-scanfile)

[Android MediaStore insertVideo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114168/android-mediastore-insertvideo)

[Capturing and Saving Videos in Android (API > 24) using File object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58283282/capturing-and-saving-videos-in-android-api-24-using-file-object)

Answer (score 1):

Posting an update. I solved this by creating a video without providing a file path. This creates the video in the DCIM folder. When the video is created I save the uri, and query the uri to make sure it still exists on the load of the application. Not exactly what i wanted but it will works